# Why my generator always returns the same value?

Tags: python, generator, python-3.4

I am implementing examples of generators with python3, and this does not work when using the `next()`:

```
def rgb():
    for r in range(256):
        for g in range(256):
            for b in range(256):
                yield r, g, b

for x in range(5):
    print(next(rgb()))
```

Output:

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 0)
```

Now, if I use the `for` works:

```
def rgb():
    for r in range(256):
        for g in range(256):
            for b in range(256):
                yield r, g, b

for x in rgb():
    print(x)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be misung the `next()` function in this case, you create a new instance of the rgb() function everytime. Try this:

```
def rgb():
    for r in range(256):
        for g in range(256):
            for b in range(256):
                yield r, g, b

it = rgb()
for x in range(5):
    print(next(it))
```

This prints

```
(0, 0, 0)
(0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 3)
(0, 0, 4)
```

as expected.